# Closeable to AutoCloseable converter utility for 3rd party java libs

Tags: java

I made this utility class to convert Closeable instances to AutoCloseable, so that I can make use of the try-with-resource exception handling mechanism of Java7. This is mainly useful for code which can not be altered.

```
public class AutoClose<T extends Closeable> implements AutoCloseable, Closeable {

    public final T instance;

    private AutoClose(T instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public static <T extends Closeable> AutoClose<T> of(T instance) {
        return new AutoClose<>(instance);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        instance.close();
    }
}
```

usage can be like :

```
try (AutoClose<SomeType> auto = AutoClose.of(someCloseable)) {
    auto.instance.someWork();
}
```

feedback much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll try to say this the best way I can...

#### Completely <strike>useless</strike> unnecessary!

Sorry. I couldn't find any better way to say it. The code that you have is well-written, but it is not necessary in the first place.

The reason is that the interface [Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) already lists `AutoCloseable` as a "superinterface", which means that `Closeable extends AutoCloseable`. So all `Closeable` objects are already `AutoCloseable`.

Which means that your code:

```
try (AutoClose<SomeType> auto = AutoClose.of(someCloseable)) {
    auto.instance.someWork();
}
```

Can instead be simply:

```
try (SomeType auto = someCloseable) {
    auto.someWork();
}
```

There is no need for your `AutoClose` wrapper.

Comment: Good lord. Time to sleep........